# Как лучше начать изучать python? Возможно по книгам или курсам или еще как-то?

Tags: python

Как лучше начать изучать python? Возможно по книгам или курсам или еще как-то?

Comment: Как начать изучать - это уже ваш выбор, но я лично начинал по курсам в YouTube

Answer (score 2):

Я дам наверное избитый совет, но все таки

Чтобы лучше начать изучать python, **надо просто сесть и начать его изучать**, а не искать как это сделать лучше :)

Подойдет любая книжка или курсы "для чайников", главное чтобы теория всегда подкреплялась какими-то обучающими задачами.

Нельзя прочитать сто книжек по питону и после этого стать крутым программистом, надо немного теории, немного практики, немного теории, немного практики и т.д.

Поэтому берите любой курс для начинающих, любую книжку про питоновскую базу и вперед.
И придумайте себе какую-нибудь задачу, которую постепенно по мере обучения будете реализовывать.